# Get DB object from JDO/DataNucleus and MongoDB with a String _id

Tags: java, mongodb, jdo, datanucleus

I am using JDO and DataNucleus to persist runtime-generated objects into MongoDB. The database objects have their own unique identifier, a string, which I put into Mongo's _id field. This works fine and I end up with, for instance, this object:

```
(in the mongo shell)
> db.CollectionName.find({"_id":"01e293bc-970d-e0b3-aac1-14109fdb7235_ZMUkU234ufY3opYPeov38T4EilNLURIb8ki"}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "01e293bc-970d-e0b3-aac1-14109fdb7235_ZMUkU234ufY3opYPeov38T4EilNLURIb8ki",
...
```

When I want to get an object back out of Mongo I make the call which I think should work:

```
PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
String keyString = "01e293bc-970d-e0b3-aac1-14109fdb7235_ZMUkU234ufY3opYPeov38T4EilNLURIb8ki";
Object dbObject = pm.getObjectById(keyString);
```

But I don't get a dbObject, instead JDO throws a JDONotFoundException. I thought perhaps I needed to specify the class of the DB object which is tough because it is runtime generated, but I added a hack which saves a pointer to the class when I persist, so that I can use it later:

```
this.savedDBclass = obj.getClass();
pm.makePersistent(obj);
...
PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
String keyString = "01e293bc-970d-e0b3-aac1-14109fdb7235_ZMUkU234ufY3opYPeov38T4EilNLURIb8ki";
Object dbObject = pm.getObjectById(this.savedDBclass, keyString);
```

and in that case I get a JDOFatalUserException "No metadata has been registered for class".

When I look at [the documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/pm.html) it seems like this procedure should be straightforward: "You can then go back to your data layer and retrieve the object as follows: Object obj = pm.getObjectById(id);"

I figure my problem is that I'm using a String instead of an ObjectId but I can't figure out the voodoo to make String IDs work. I read in the documentation "A DataNucleus extension is to pass in a String form of the identity to the above method" but we aren't using that extension, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you read the JDO spec which is very clear what is an "identity" (a String is not it), and what is a PK value. You don't post the class itself, so people are left to guesswork. To get an "identity" you can easily enough do

```
Object identity = pm.newObjectIdInstance(MyObject.class, "my_pk_value_when_string");
```

and that is what goes into `pm.getObjectById(id)`. You then look at the log if having problems.

Comment: Quoth JDO spec: "Application identity is managed by you, the developer. Under application identity, the values of one or more persistent fields in an object determine its JDO identity. These fields are called primary key fields. ... Primary key fields must be primitives, primitive wrappers, Strings, or Dates."

Is this where the "JDO spec is very clear"? To me that means clearly that a primary key field which is a String can be used as the identity.

Comment: My misunderstanding of the spec notwithstanding, your advice was spot on. I got the runtime 'identity' Object as you suggest and got my object! Thank you.